# Database SQL query stuck

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query

I have to find name of customers who have rented "Comedy" movies but have not rented "Drama" movies.
I have written following query but I'm not getting the correct result. I think not rented "Drama" part is not working in my query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(customer.first_name,' ',customer.last_name) as Name
FROM  rental 
JOIN  inventory ON rental.inventory_id=inventory.inventory_id
JOIN  customer ON rental.customer_id=customer.customer_id
JOIN  film ON film.film_id=inventory.film_id
JOIN  film_category ON film_category.film_id=film.film_id
WHERE film_category.category_id=5 and 
      film_category.category_id<>7
ORDER by Name;
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Comment: What makes that even worse is that you got several reasonable answers.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned in other answers a 5 isn't a 7, but also you need to be careful when using DISTINCT , as you could have two customers with the same name, use a group by clause instead.

The best way to deal with this is a sub-query, CTE or Temporary table depending on the size of database and the version of MySQL you are running. These will be the least of work for MySQL and should return the result set in the fastest way.

Your starter for 10 is a sub-query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(customer.first_name,' ',customer.last_name) as Name
FROM  rental 
JOIN  inventory ON rental.inventory_id=inventory.inventory_id
JOIN  customer ON rental.customer_id=customer.customer_id
JOIN  film ON film.film_id=inventory.film_id
JOIN  film_category ON film_category.film_id=film.film_id
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT customer.customer_id
    FROM  rental 
    JOIN  inventory ON rental.inventory_id=inventory.inventory_id
    JOIN  customer ON rental.customer_id=customer.customer_id
    JOIN  film ON film.film_id=inventory.film_id
    JOIN  film_category ON film_category.film_id=film.film_id
    WHERE film_category.category_id=7
    GROUP BY customer.customer_id
) as DRAMA
ON DRAMA.customer_id=customer.customer_id
WHERE film_category.category_id=5 AND 
DRAMA.customer_id is NULL
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
ORDER by Name;
```

Basically what we are doing here is forming two sets of data and just getting the customers from set A that don't overlap with set B.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns a row for each rental where the `category_id` is 5 and isn't 7 - which is a redundant condition since 5 is obviously not 7.

One easy way to approach such problems is to count the number of rows each customer has with `category_id`s of 5s and 7s:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(customer.first_name,' ',customer.last_name) as Name
FROM     rental 
JOIN     inventory ON rental.inventory_id=inventory.inventory_id
JOIN     customer ON rental.customer_id=customer.customer_id
JOIN     film ON film.film_id=inventory.film_id
JOIN     film_category ON film_category.film_id=film.film_id
GROUP BY customer.first_name, customer.last_name
HAVING   COUNT(CASE film_category.category_id WHEN 5 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
         COUNT(CASE film_category.category_id WHEN 7 THEN 1 END) = 0
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mureinik If I need to find just the number of rows returned. Like in this example count is 78. How should I change select statement for that? So that I only get output as 78 and not their names or id's

Comment: You can just wrap it with another query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT... `

Answer (score 0):

You should start thinking in a set way. Let us have a set A as a set of customers who rented 'Comedy' and set B of customers who rented 'Drama'. Then you simply need A - B. It can be written in MySql for example using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(customer.first_name,' ',customer.last_name) as Name
FROM  customer 
WHERE customer.customer_id IN (
    SELECT rental.customer_id
    FROM rental 
    JOIN inventory ON rental.inventory_id=inventory.inventory_id
    JOIN  film ON film.film_id=inventory.film_id
    JOIN  film_category ON film_category.film_id=film.film_id
    WHERE film_category.category_id=5
) AND 
      customer.customer_id NOT IN (
    SELECT rental.customer_id
    FROM rental 
    JOIN inventory ON rental.inventory_id=inventory.inventory_id
    JOIN  film ON film.film_id=inventory.film_id
    JOIN  film_category ON film_category.film_id=film.film_id
    WHERE film_category.category_id=7
)
```

Be aware that this query will work if you do not have `NULL` in `rental.customer_id`.